# Proving that proposed vectors actually form a basis for Null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the matrix

A = \begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&6&9\\3&-2&1&4&-1\\-1&0&-1&-2&-1\\2&3&5&7&8\end{bmatrix}
and I am asked to find a basis for the Null space of A, as well as verify that my proposed vectors actually form a basis for the Null space. 
I got the RREF of matrix A and ended up with the following result for my basis:

B = {**v** = (-1, -1, 1, 0, 0), **u** = (-2, -1, 0, 1, 0), **w** = (-1, -2, 0, 0, 1)}

My problem arises in trying to "prove" that these vectors actually form the basis. From my understanding, a subset of a vector space is a basis if the vectors in it are linearly independent and the span of the vectors equals the vector space.  Now, when trying to prove that my vectors are linearly independent, I am faced with a problem, as I obtain the following matrix (which will inevitably have a free variable, making the columns linearly dependent):

\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&-1&0\\-1&-1&-2&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

I'm having a hard time understanding where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to show that

$$av+bc+cw=0$$

implies that $a=b=c=0$ and hence the system is linearly independent.

And in doing so, you form the augmented system.

The last column is the augmented column and it doesn't introduce a free variable.

You can conclude that $a=0$ from the third row, conclude that $b=0$ from the fourth row and conclude that $c=0$ from the fifth row.

Remark:

Since the first two rows of $A$ are not multiple of each other, the rank of $A$ is at least $2$, hence by rank-nullity theorem, the nullity is at most $3$. We have found $3$ independent elements of the nullspace of $A$, hence we have found a basis.

Comment: Thank you! It completely went over my head that there isn't necessarily a free variable.  I have a follow up question if you don't mind; how do I prove that the Span(B) = Null(A) (the second requirement in order to prove that it is indeed a basis)? Is it somehow related to the fact that the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: elements of $B$ are clearly in the nullspace of $A$, the question is whether we left of any element of the nullspace of $A$, by rank nullity theorem, we know that the nullity is $3$. Hence we did not left out any element and it is a basis. i.e. I have answered that question in the remark.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&6&9\\3&-2&1&4&-1\\-1&0&-1&-2&-1\\2&3&5&7&8\end{bmatrix}$$ has rank $2$ and nullity $3$

Thus if you show your three vectors $$v = (-1, -1, 1, 0, 0), u = (-2, -1, 0, 1, 0), w = (-1, -2, 0, 0, 1)$$ in the null space  are linearly independent, then you have a basis for your null space.

You may verify the linear independence of  these vectors by row reduced echelon form of the matrix whose rows are your$ v$,$u$, and $ w.$
Thus B={$v,u,w$} is indeed a basis for your null space.